# Blue Yeti USB cable issues?

Tags: microphone, usb, cable

I've had a standard Blue Yeti mic I've used for a few years, pretty happy with it.

For one project I run the Yeti through a USB hub into a laptop. I've wanted to get a second cable to make the setup easier. However, I've been frustrated that each of the new USB cables (different brands) gives an audible hissing noise on the input, whereas the original one doesn't.

- Original cable, about 6 ft long: Works fine, no hissing in this configuration.
- Replacement cable #1, about 6 ft long: Gives hissing sound.
- Replacement cable #2, about 4.5 ft long: Gives hissing sound.

I notice Blue doesn't sell replacement cables on their website at this time.

Is there any particular construction or brand of USB cable that the Yeti works best with?

Comment: This question asks for recommendations, but has a basic premise which is incorrect. Blue Yeti is noted for sheer quantity of issues/problems - would advise getting something else.

Answer (score 1):

USB is USB, at this level. It doesn't carry sound, it carries data, so it cannot in & of itself add hiss.

Blue say their cable is a standard mini USB cable, nothing special - https://twitter.com/BlueMicrophones/status/1001516846032609280